# Error: A field or property with the name 'ProductID' was not found on the selected data source (asp.net c#, sql)

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I'm using a Gridview on asp.net to display my sql data, and it displayed the error:

> A field or property with the name 'ProductID' was not found on the selected data source

Below is my sql coding:

```
public List<Product> getWomenProductAll()
    {
        List<Product> prodList = new List<Product>();

        string prod_Name, prod_Desc, Prod_Image, prod_ID;
        decimal unit_Price;

        string queryStr = "SELECT ProductID, Name, Description, Model, UnitPrice FROM WomenProduct Order By Name";

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connStr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryStr, conn);            

        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            prod_ID = dr["ProductID"].ToString();
            prod_Name = dr["Name"].ToString();
            prod_Desc = dr["Description"].ToString();
            Prod_Image = dr["Model"].ToString();
            unit_Price = decimal.Parse(dr["UnitPrice"].ToString());
            Product a = new Product(prod_ID, prod_Name, prod_Desc, unit_Price, Prod_Image);
            prodList.Add(a);
        }

        conn.Close();
        dr.Close();
        dr.Dispose();

        return prodList;
    }
```

Here is my c# coding to bind to gridview:

```
 protected void bind ()
{
    List<Product> prodList = new List<Product>();
    prodList = aProd.getWomenProductAll();
    gvProduct.DataSource = prodList;
    gvProduct.DataBind();
}
```

Please advise if there is any error in my coding thanks.
Here is the entire product class:

```
public class Product
{string _connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
//private string _connStr = Properties.Settings.Default.DBConnStr;
private string _prodID = null;
private string _prodName = string.Empty;
private string _prodDesc = ""; // this is another way to specify empty string
private decimal _unitPrice = 0;
private string _prodImage = "";


// Default constructor
public Product()
{
}

// Constructor that take in all data required to build a Product object
public Product(string prodID, string prodName, string prodDesc,
               decimal unitPrice, string prodImage)
{
    _prodID = prodID;
    _prodName = prodName;
    _prodDesc = prodDesc;
    _unitPrice = unitPrice;
    _prodImage = prodImage;

}

// Constructor that take in all except product ID
public Product(string prodName, string prodDesc,
       decimal unitPrice, string prodImage, int stockLevel)
    : this(null, prodName, prodDesc, unitPrice, prodImage)
{
}

// Constructor that take in only Product ID. The other attributes will be set to 0 or empty.
public Product(string prodID)
    : this(prodID, "", "", 0, "")
{
}

// Get/Set the attributes of the Product object.
// Note the attribute name (e.g. Product_ID) is same as the actual database field name.
// This is for ease of referencing.
public string Product_ID
{
    get { return _prodID; }
    set { _prodID = value; }
}
public string Product_Name
{
    get { return _prodName; }
    set { _prodName = value; }
}
public string Product_Desc
{
    get { return _prodDesc; }
    set { _prodDesc = value; }
}
public decimal Unit_Price
{
    get { return _unitPrice; }
    set { _unitPrice = value; }
}
public string Product_Image
{
    get { return _prodImage; }
    set { _prodImage = value; }
}

        //Below as the Class methods for some DB operations. 
    public Product getWomenProduct(string prodID)
    {

        Product prodDetail = null;

        string prod_Name, prod_Desc, Prod_Image;
        decimal unit_Price;
        string queryStr = "SELECT ProductID, Name, Description, Model, UnitPrice FROM WomenProduct WHERE ProductID = @ProdID";

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connStr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryStr, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProdID", prodID);

        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.Read())
        {
            prodID = dr["ProductID"].ToString();
            prod_Name = dr["Name"].ToString();
            prod_Desc = dr["Description"].ToString();
            Prod_Image = dr["Model"].ToString();
            unit_Price = decimal.Parse(dr["UnitPrice"].ToString());


            prodDetail = new Product(prodID, prod_Name, prod_Desc, unit_Price, Prod_Image);
        }
        else
        {
            prodDetail = null;
        }

        conn.Close();
        dr.Close();
        dr.Dispose();

        return prodDetail;
    }
    public Product getMenProduct(string prodID)
    {

        Product prodDetail = null;

        string prod_Name, prod_Desc, Prod_Image;
        decimal unit_Price;
        string queryStr = "SELECT ProductID, Name, Description, Model, 

    public List<Product> getWomenProductAll()
    {
        List<Product> prodList = new List<Product>();

        string prod_Name, prod_Desc, Prod_Image, prod_ID;
        decimal unit_Price;

        string queryStr = "SELECT ProductID, Name, Description, Model, UnitPrice FROM WomenProduct Order By Name";

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connStr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryStr, conn);            

        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            prod_ID = dr["ProductID"].ToString();
            prod_Name = dr["Name"].ToString();
            prod_Desc = dr["Description"].ToString();
            Prod_Image = dr["Model"].ToString();
            unit_Price = decimal.Parse(dr["UnitPrice"].ToString());
            Product a = new Product(prod_ID, prod_Name, prod_Desc, unit_Price, Prod_Image);
            prodList.Add(a);
        }

        conn.Close();
        dr.Close();
        dr.Dispose();

        return prodList;
    }
```

Comment: Which line is giving you this error and what exception are you getting precisely?

Comment: The line `gvProduct.Databind();` It states:" An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code" Thanks @KiNeTiC

Comment: Can we see the Product class?

Comment: That's probably not a SQL error.

Comment: can put a breakpoint and look at gvProduct.DataSource has the objects you want?

Comment: Hi, I've added the entire Product.cs please take a look thank you! @KiNeTiC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Product class has a Product_ID property, but your binding is on "ProductID" (no underscore). You need to fix one of these.

Comment: @denissapop this would be a lot easier if you were consistent with your naming. prod_ID, prodID, ProductID and Product_ID all referring to the same thing.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your advice! :)